# Using Google App Engine to display a Rss/Atom feed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rss, feed, atom-feed

Im thinking of setting up a **Google App that simply displays an RSS or Atom feed**. The idea is that every once in a while (a cron job or at the push of a magic button) the feed is read and copied into the apps internal data, ready to be viewed. This would be done in Python.

I found [this](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/appengine/articles/gdata.html) page that seems to explain what I want to do. But that is assuming Im using some of the other Google products as it relies on the Google API.

My idea was more in line that added some new content, hosted it locally on my machine, went to the Google App administration panel, pushed a button and **my (locally hosted) feed was read and copied**.

My questions now are:

- Is the RSS (or Atom, one is enough) format specified enough to handle add/edit/delete?
- Are there any flavors or such I should worry about?
- Have this been done before? Would save me some work.

Comment: I just can't understand what you are trying to do... of course you can manipulate RSS/ATOM feeds on AppEngine... and its pretty straightforward.

Comment: Maybe it is to straightforward, Im trying to find some documentation on it but its a bit lacking. Maybe I should rephrase the question? What part was unclear? Source feed -> google app copies -> feed can now be seen on *.appspot.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use the [universal feed parser](http://www.feedparser.org/) library, which will take care of most of these issues for you. Another option would be to use a PubSubHubbub-powered service such as [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com/), which will POST updates to you in a pre-sanitized form, eliminating most of your polling and parsing issues.

Answer (score 0):

What about using an additional library, like for instance [Feedparser](http://www.feedparser.org/)?